# Installshield: How to copy an adobe reader plugin to the correct plugin folder

Tags: installshield

I setup preconditions to make sure that I have adobe reader 9 or 10 installed. How to I copy the plugin to the correct location? The user might have 9,10 or both installed and I need to copy it to the right location.

I think the search might help me but not sure how to accomplish it. i am using installshield 2013

Answer (score 1):

The basic plan is something like this, pretty simple:

- create folder searches for both versions
- now create two custom folders in your Files view, based on the searches
- add in the newly created folders your plug-ins
- now you need to set a condition on the components of the created folders and files from within, so they install only if the search finds the corespondent Adobe version

Comment: I am totally new to installshield 2013. I understand the 1st part but I have no idea how to set the others. How do I create the folders based on the search?

Comment: I don't use InstallShield but the approach is the same in all tools. I use and work on the development of Advanced Installer  http://www.advancedinstaller.com/.